# Users exiting the page during refresh token rotation causes invalid refresh tokens

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, auth0, refresh-token

We're running into a situation where occasionally users are exiting the page during refresh token rotation. This results in the user not receiving the new token (as they leave the page before a HTTP response is received) and means that their original refresh token is now invalid. Consequently, users need to log back in.

To reproduce the flow it will help to simulate slow network conditions:

1. User hits the refresh token endpoint on a slow connection
2. Before the refresh token endpoint can respond, close/navigate away from the website
3. User now has invalid token due to not getting the updated token in the above response.

After some googling, I'm struggling to find any approaches to mitigate this situation without disabling refresh token rotation completely. Any ideas?

Comment: is this not the expected behaviour? Could you also add which technologies you are using so users can help you better

Comment: As a user, it isn't expected behaviour that I can accidentally invalidate my auth details depending on what time I navigate away from a page. Tech is just website with fetch requests.